# What PocketWizard units do I need for a Sekonic L-758DR-U to control flash power with a Fuji camera and Nikon flash?

Tags: fujifilm, wireless-flash, pocket-wizard

I have a Fuji X-T1 and just came into possession of two PocketWizard Plus IV transceivers and I am using a Nikon SB-910 in manual.  I also have a Sekonic L-758DR-U light meter that works with PocketWizards.

Now, to control the power of the flash from the L-758DR-U, I need either the FlexTT5 or MiniTT1 for Nikon.

So I am new to pocket wizards.  With the PocketWizard Plus IV transceiver on my X-T1 hot shoe, and the XB-910 with the MiniTT1 can I then control power with the L-758DR-U?

From the pocket wizard web site:

"The MiniTT1 and FlexTT5 are compatible with any PocketWizard radio for triggering manual flash or remote cameras."

Sekonic says on their site that other PW units can control flash groups but only the FlexTT5/MiniTT1 will control flash power.

So hoping that I can buy the FlexTT5 and work with the Plus IV in the x-t1 hot shoe to control flash power from the L-758DR-U.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? It seems you already realize the PW IVs can't control the power of the SB-910.

Comment: Pocket Wizards are expensive and often more complicated/less reliable than many options now on the market. They made a name when they were pretty much the *only* player that gave wireless flash the same capabilities as using the same flash on a hot shoe or via a hot shoe cord. That us no longer the case.

Comment: The MiniTT1 is a transmitter only. And remember that the Plus IV units only work on regular channels, not ControlTL (which are used for TTL and advanced features on the TT1/TT5.) You'd have to set everything to regular channels for them to work together.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no power control from a Sekonic L-758DR meter** (there is from the much newer 478 models).  There is *group* control for triggering, but that's it.  Whether you have the TTL units or the PlusIVs probably doesn't make any difference, since the Plus IVs also understand the PW group control signaling.

In addition, the main reason to get the TTL PW units all don't matter with a Fuji camera body.  You won't have TTL. You won't have HSS. You'd only have remote power/group control--if you can use them on a non-Nikon hotshoe (I think you can; not 100% sure, so I'd check). Overall, in my opinion, it's a waste of $400+ dollars to get the flex/mini combo just to have group control from your meter.

You *can* control the power of the flash from the on-camera TTL radio transmitter. But there are a lot of just-as-reliable, much cheaper, fuller-featured triggers using 2.4 GHz that are roughly a quarter of the price of the PW TTL units (e.g., Godox X1).  And you can still trigger your lights for readings with the meter if you simply cable an additional transmitter to your meter, or use the test button on an in-hand transmitter. Again, paying a premium to simply have built-in triggering/group control may not be worth it to you. Maybe it will.  Just remember that trigger expenses multiple along with the number of lights you use.